# Android methods are not mocked when using Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I'm writing a test which purpose is to test some methods in subclass of `Adapter` class (used by `RecyclerView`). To mock adapter behavior I've chosen Mockito library.

Here's a simple test:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter;

public class TestAdapter {

    @Test
    public void testAdapter() throws Exception {
        Adapter adapter = Mockito.mock(Adapter.class);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Nothing should happen but `NullPointerException` is thrown instead.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(RecyclerView.java:5380)
    at pl.toro.test.adapter.TestAdapter.testAdapter(TestAdapter.java:38)
    ...
```

I've also tried with `spy` instead of `mock`

```
@Test
public void testAdapterWithDoNothing() throws Exception {
    Adapter adapter = Mockito.spy(new Adapter() {...});
    doNothing().when(adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But this fails at second line (notice this is just a mock setup)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyChanged(RecyclerView.java:8946)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(RecyclerView.java:5380)
    at pl.toro.test.adapter.TestAdapter.testAdapterWithDoNothing(TestAdapter.java:59)
    ...
```

Is it possible to mock support classes with Mockito in unit tests?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Android support classes obey [the same rules as the rest of Java](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito) regarding what can or can't be mocked; unfortunately, the method you're referring to ([notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)) is final. You may also consider this a hazard of *mocking types you don't own*, as the `final` semantics affect whether the class can be mocked.

Internally, Mockito works by creating a "subclass" (actually a proxy implementation) of the class you're mocking. Because `final` method resolution can happen at compile time, Java skips the polymorphic method lookup and directly invokes your method. This is slightly faster in production, but without the method lookup Mockito loses its only way to redirect your call.

This is a common occurrence across the Android SDK (recently solved with [a modified version of android.jar](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#mocking-dependencies) which has the `final` modifiers stripped off) and support libraries. You might consider one of the following resolutions:

1. Refactor your system to introduce a wrapper class that you control, which is simple enough to require little or no testing.
2. Use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/), which uses a special Android-SDK-targeted JVM classloader that can rewrite calls into mockable equivalents (and also parses and supplies Android resources for testing without an emulator). Robolectric provides enough Android-specific "shadows" (replacement implementations) that you can usually avoid writing your own, but also allows for custom shadows for cases like support libraries.
3. Use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage), which extends Mockito or EasyMock using a special classloader that also rewrites the bytecode of your system under test. Unlike Robolectric, it is not Android-targeted, making it a more general-purpose solution but generally requiring more setup.

   PowerMock is an extension of Mockito, so it provides strictly more functionality, but personally I try to refactor around any problem that would require it.

Comment: I thought this may be the case that support libraries are not replaced like androd.jar: "At runtime, tests will be executed against a modified version of android.jar where all final modifiers have been stripped off". I'm testing class that takes `Adapter` in constructor, but I need to verify that notify methods are called on this adapter so the 1. solution doesn't help I think. I'm already using Roblectric but it's way too slow, that's why I'm trying to mock it. I'm familiar with PowerMock but I didn't want to add additional test dependency - it's look like I've no choice. Thanks Jeff!

Comment: there is another option: instrumented tests. They are slow, but you can use Android classes in your tests. See https://medium.com/@yair.kukielka/android-unit-tests-explained-219b04dc55b5#.1r4eqwfcb

Comment: @Yair: Though instrumented tests are an effective approach to test with real implementations (on a device or in an emulator), they would be even less appropriate for using mocks as in the original question.

Comment: @JeffBowman I agree, you can either use Mockito or create an instrumented test, but both would be a bit strange. I think Mockito makes UI testing a bit cumbersome sometimes.