# Why is my JSONObject related unit test failing?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running my tests using `gradle testFlavorType`

```
JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
jsonObject1.put("test", "test");
jsonObject2.put("test", "test");
assertEquals(jsonObject1.get("test"), jsonObject2.get("test"));
```

The above test succeeds.

```
jsonObject = new SlackMessageRequest(channel, message).buildBody();
String channelAssertion = jsonObject.getString(SlackMessageRequest.JSON_KEY_CHANNEL);
String messageAssertion = jsonObject.getString(SlackMessageRequest.JSON_KEY_TEXT);
assertEquals(channel, channelAssertion);
assertEquals(message, messageAssertion);
```

But the above two requests fail. The stack trace says that channelAssertion and messageAssertion are null, but not sure why. My question is: **Why are the above two asserts failing?**

Below is the `SlackMessageRequest`.

```
public class SlackMessageRequest
        extends BaseRequest {
    // region Variables

    public static final String JSON_KEY_TEXT = "text";
    public static final String JSON_KEY_CHANNEL = "channel";

    private String mChannel;
    private String mMessage;

    // endregion

    // region Constructors

    public SlackMessageRequest(String channel, String message) {
        mChannel = channel;
        mMessage = message;
    }

    // endregion

    // region Methods

    @Override
    public MethodType getMethodType() {
        return MethodType.POST;
    }    

    @Override
    public JSONObject buildBody() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
        body.put(JSON_KEY_TEXT, getMessage());
        body.put(JSON_KEY_CHANNEL, getChannel());
        return body;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrl() {
        return "http://localhost:1337";
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return mMessage;
    }

    public String getChannel() {
        return mChannel;
    }

// endregion
}
```

Below is the stacktrace:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<@tk> but was:<null>
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:100)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:107)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals(TestCase.java:269)
    at com.example.app.http.request.SlackMessageRequestTest.testBuildBody(SlackMessageRequestTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

***EDIT 5:55PM EST***

I've figured out that I can log with `System.out.println("")` and then see the results by running `gradle testFlavorType --debug` and by trial and error I've discovered the following weird situation:

```
@Override
public JSONObject buildBody() throws JSONException {
    System.out.println("buildBody mChannel = " + mChannel);
    System.out.println("buildBody mMessage = " + mMessage);
    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    body.put(JSON_KEY_TEXT, getMessage());
    body.put(JSON_KEY_CHANNEL, getChannel());

    if (body.length() != 0) {
        Iterator<String> keys = body.keys();

        if (keys.hasNext()) {
            do {
                String key = keys.next();
                System.out.println("keys: " + key);
            } while (keys.hasNext());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("There are no keys????");
    }

    return body;
}
```

For some reason, "There are no keys????" is printing out?!?!?!?! Why?!

***EDIT 6:20PM EST***

I've figured out how to debug unit tests. According to the debugger, the assigned JSONObject is returning `"null"`. I have no clue what this means (see below). Since I think this is relevant, my gradle file includes the following:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

It's especially strange because if I construct a JSONObject inside the test, then everything works fine. But if it is part of the original application's code, then it doesn't work and does the above.

[image]

Comment: Please add the stack trace.

Comment: @Zoltán, I have added the stack trace.

Comment: That used to work, but seems that it has to be run under instrumentation artifact now.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As Lucas says, JSON is bundled up with the Android SDK, so you are working with a stub.

The current solution is to pull JSON from Maven Central like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation 'org.json:json:20210307'
}
```

You can replace the version `20210307` with the [the latest one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) depending on the Android API. It is [not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564936/what-version-of-org-json-is-built-into-android) which version of the maven artefact corresponds exactly/most closely to what ships with Android.

Alternatively, you can download and include the jar:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation files('libs/json.jar')
}
```

Note that you also need to use Android Studio 1.1 or higher and at least build tools version 22.0.0 or above for this to work.

Related issue: [#179461](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179461)

Comment: This no longer works for me. It did on an old project, but now I'm still getting `null` when trying to create a new `JSONObject`. I'm using `testCompile 'org.json:json:20160810'`. I also tried `configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force 'org.json:json:20160810' }`, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I just found this in my gradle output:

`WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for flavorDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages`

Comment: Thank you. You have no idea how much this solution helps my blood pressure.

Comment: Ha ha ... yes ... I helped me very very much! +1

Comment: The version is very old and may not work. Use `org.json:json:20180130`.

Comment: can use the latest version from here (at the time of writing this May, 2020 was the latest) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Comment: Since testCompile is deprecated, you can use
`testImplementation 'org.json:json:20201115'`
don't forget to clean before running your tests again

Answer (score 54):

The class JSONObject is part of the android SDK. That means that is not available for unit testing by default.

From http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

> The android.jar file that is used to run unit tests does not contain
>   any actual code - that is provided by the Android system image on real
>   devices. Instead, all methods throw exceptions (by default). This is
>   to make sure your unit tests only test your code and do not depend on
>   any particular behaviour of the Android platform (that you have not
>   explicitly mocked e.g. using Mockito).

When you set the test options to

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

you are fixing the "Method ... not mocked." problem, but the outcome is that when your code uses `new JSONObject()` you are not using the real method, you are using a mock method that doesn't do anything, it just returns a default value. That's the reason the object is `null`.

You can find different ways of solving the problem in this question: [Android methods are not mocked when using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31777188/3099776)

Answer (score 0):

Well, my first hunch would be that your `getMessage()` method returns `null`. You could show the body of that method in your question and have us find the answer for you, but you should probably research how to debug android applications using breakpoints.
That way you can run your code step by step and see the values of each variable at every step. That would show you your problem in no time, and it's a skill you should definitely master as soon as possible if you intend to get seriously involved in programming.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion. I have already provided the body of the `getMessage()` method. It is part of the `SlackMessageRequest`, did you look at that? I don't see how it could be null however. I'm pretty familiar with debugging, but I'm running these tests in terminal so I haven't figured out a way I can debug them. Any suggestions on how I can achieve that?

Comment: @tambykojak maybe this can help https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/
my next hunch would be that `message` and `channel` are `null` when passed into the constructor. You didn't show the part of code where you initialize those variables. If setting up a debugging environment is too complicated, you could always add temporary logging between some lines.

Comment: I've read that blog multiple times, but it doesn't solve that issue. Even if `channel` and `test` are `null`, the test should still pass based on the logic provided.

Comment: Yeah, it should work with `null`, you're right. Anyway. Add some logging or simple `System.out.println` at key parts and see where the `null`s come from.