# Android immediately created Pair elements are null

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio

As show in the image, I create a `Pair` of `String` but they are `null` (as shown in the debugger)

[image]

What's wrong? I'd really like to avoid littering my project with a reimplementation of `Pair<A, B>`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `android.support.v4.util.Pair` instead of `android.util.Pair`

Comment: WOW, it works, but that's make totally no sense! I just replace all my imports after this. Thanks much!

Comment: Could you please explain what's happen in non support case and why it's not working as expected?

Comment: @Natasha, have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32822468/4229930)

Comment: Awesome! Also with androidx library, it's updated to `androidx.core.util.Pair`.

Answer (score 9):

Using `androidx.core.util.Pair` instead of `android.util.Pair` should also work with unit tests