# What version of org.json is built into Android?

Tags: android, org.json

I'm using an open source library that depends on `org.json:json:20090211`.  Evidently there are some API differences between version `20090211` and whatever version is provided by Android.  When I enable ProGuard minimization, I see this warning:

> Warning: com.esri.core.geometry.JSONObjectEnumerator: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String[] getNames(org.json.JSONObject)' in library class org.json.JSONObject

That method is present in the current reference implementation of [`JSONObject`](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java), so I assume it was added sometime before version `20090211`, as opposed to removed after it, which means the version included in Android is older.  I'd like to diff that version against `20090211` and see what needs to be done to make the library that depends on `20090211` compatible with Android.

**What version of org.json is included in Android?**

(I know I could rename `org.json` and change the dependency to the renamed version, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.  Such a change is unlikely to be accepted upstream.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm uncertain of this answer, but the Android version may correspond to no official version.  This comment appears in the AOSP source for [`JSONObject`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/f2f7880a40aed1c8d9c27db49226e47396556aac/libcore/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java):

```
// Note: this class was written without inspecting the non-free org.json sourcecode.
```

The org.json license is identical to the MIT license, with one addition:

> The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil.

So perhaps Google considered that clause too restrictive, and felt the need to reimplement `org.json` from scratch.

Comment: This is really annoying, because the two are incompatible.

Third party libraries using official version of org.json will be broken when used in the Android app.

For this reason, I forked the offical version of org.json with another package name in my own projects. Which should be done by Google IMHO.