# Unable to catch exception in Kotlin JUnit 4 Test

Tags: java, android, junit, kotlin

I want to check if a String has a valid JSON format in a unit tests.

To do this, I try creating a new JSONObject from the string and catching any possible Exceptions that can be thrown.

However, when running the code below, no Exception is caught

```
@Test
fun checkFunctionWithStringToJSONTest() {
    val invalidJSON = "INVALIDJSON--"
    try {
        JSONObject(invalidJSON)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        try {
            JSONArray(invalidJSON)
        } catch (ex1: Exception) {
            assert(false)
        }
    }
    assert(true)
}
```

Evaluating the same expression in the debugger shows that an Exception should be thrown, but is never caught.

Why is this happening?

I'm Using `JUnit 4.12`, `hamcrest-library:1.3` and `Kotlin 1.2.31` in an Android studio Android project

**EDIT:**
As pointed out here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822468/3708094
JSONObject is a part of the android framework and not available in Unit Tests. Most likely this is related to the cause of the question above.

Even if it is not available, no Exception is caught, but something is thrown according to the debuggers evaluate tool.

Comment: Maybe it's a `Throwable` which isn't an `Exception`?

Comment: `Method threw 'java.lang.RuntimeException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()`. So it was an Exception. Luckily, this set me in on right track in identifying the missing org.json package in my unit tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, the origin of the problem is with JSONObject being a part of the Android system libraries.

For me the solution was to manually add JSONObject in gradle to the testImplementation

```
dependencies {
    ...
   testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180130'
}
```