# JSONObject's method toString() is always null

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm trying to test a method with a `JSONObject` parameter, but when I create an instance of `JSONObject` and put some values, the `toString()` value returned from the instance is null. I'm expecting a JSON string. See code below.

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject()
jsonObject.put("message", "hello")
println(jsonObject.toString()) // actual: null, expected: {"message":"hello"}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385092/why-is-my-jsonobject-related-unit-test-failing - I'm assuming this is a unit test you're writing?

Comment: @sbso yes, I'm writing a unit test

Comment: I just include this line `testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180813'` in the `build.gradle` file. After that, it is now printing as expected. For the latest update, go to this link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json.