# Same Java unit test returning different results in a plain Java project and an Android project

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I have a plain old Java project and in it, a simple Java class that has a method to validate JSON strings.

```
public class Validator {
    public boolean isJSONValid(String jsonString) {
        try {
            new JSONObject(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            try {
                new JSONArray(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException ex1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I added JUnit 5 from the Gradle file to write a unit test for this method.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.0'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20220924'
}
```

Here are the unit tests.

```
class ValidatorTest {
    @Test
    void jsonStringIsValid() {
        Validator validator = new Validator();
        String json =
                "{" +
                        "   \"name\":\"John\"," +
                        "   \"age\":15," +
                        "   \"gender\":\"M\"" +
                        "}";
        Assertions.assertTrue(validator.isJSONValid(json));
    }

    @Test
    void jsonStringIsInvalid() {
        Validator validator = new Validator();
        String json =
                        "   \"name\":\"John\"," +
                        "   \"age\":15," +
                        "   \"gender\":\"M\"";
        Assertions.assertFalse(validator.isJSONValid(json));
    }
}
```

The unit test passes correctly and everything is good here.

Then I ported the same Java class to an Android project (using Java) and added JUnit 5 again and added the same unit test over there as well.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But strangely, when I run the same tests in the Android project, the second test method `jsonStringIsInvalid()` passes even if I give it an invalid JSON string!

Here I have removed the starting and closing curly braces to intentionally make it an invalid JSON string. But as you can see, the test passed all the same.

[image]

The same tests run in the Java projects, works as expected. I added the `assertTrue` in the `jsonStringIsInvalid()` method to deliberately show the error for this example's sake.

[image]

The code, JUnit version are all the same. Only difference is I used IntelliJ to run the Java project and Android Studio to run the Android project.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I'd appreciate any help understanding this. I have uploaded the code below if that helps.

[Java project](https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/JavaProject) | [Android project](https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/AndroidProject)

Comment: Youir unit test should test both cases.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get you. The unit test method fails if I pass a wrong string in the Java project. In the Android project, the same test passes successfully even if I pass a wrong string. That's the problem.

Comment: The code you have posted shows a test which checks that correct JSON causes isJSONValid to return true. You talk about a test which checks that it returns false when the JSON isn't valid, and say that it behaves differently between Android studio and Intellij. The problem is that you *haven't shown that test* -- so it's hard to give you any help about why it might behave differently.

Comment: It's the same test method. Anyway I updated the question with a bit more details and a screenshot. Hopefully that clears things more.

Comment: Then your test has successfully shown that the validator does not do the validation you think it does.  In particular, the validator seems to sometimes permit absence of a closing brace, probably depending on the particular implementation of JSONObject.  Now you need to decide whether that is a 'bug' or not.

Comment: @undefinedsymbol It's not just the curly brace. If I pass a string like "asdf", it would still consider it as valid JSON. And the `JSONObject` is from the same third-party library (not written by me). The implementation is the same. Only the platform is different (Java vs Android).

Comment: I wonder why your question doesn't contain any debugging attempts? Is the validator correctly called? Are the json objects created or not? How do they look like, although the JSON is invalid? Is there an exception?

Comment: @Tom When I called the methods on validator from say, an Activity, the method actually works as expected. Only when it's called from inside the unit test, it returns wrong results. I'm not sure what else I can do. I'm not really a Java/Android developer so if there are any suggestions, I'd be happy to try out.

Comment: Don't have one test, edit it, and run it again expecting it to fail. Have separate test for the valid JSON and the invalid JSON cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Apparently the JSON-Java library that comes bundled with the Android SDK by default is not available in the test module.

So I explicitly added the `testImplementation` of the library to my Gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.json:json:20220924'
}
```

And the unit tests now work as expected.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41398830/1077789)